# Finding character types in a particular word ( regex ) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I find lower case / special characters in a word

for example :

```
              HELLO  (this is good)
              HeLL0 ( not good)
              H$L&0  (not good) .
```

I have two regex statements that I am evaluating this value by but does not seem to help

```
        var pattern = /[A-Z]*[A-Z,]+/;
        var pattern2= /[^a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()+-_?<>~`\|{}]+/;
```

Comment: what are expected match and rejects? only capital letter words?

Comment: yes , I am looking for only capital letter words

Comment: Then matching `/^[A-Z]+$/` should work for you.

Comment: @anubhava what if we want to match multiple capital letter words in a same line? `\b[A-Z]+\b` doesn't seem to work. `\b` considers boundaries at special characters.

Comment: @jkshah: I guess OP needs to provide some example inputs to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe You need regex like this:

```
/[^A-Z]/
```

This should pick up every character, which is not a capital letter. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: /[^A-Z ]/ or /[^A-Z\s]/ if space is valid. Add a global flag if you need to match everything in the string

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex to mach only when the entire string is capital letters:

```
/^[A-Z]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to use this simple code to make that test.

```
var txt="Hello"; //Your text
var pattern =  /^[A-Z]+$/; //Pattern for only Mayus
if ((txt.match(pattern)) && (txt!='')) // If for comprove if is only mayus and isn't empty.
{
     //Correct
}
else
{
    //No correct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for only capital letter words

Try following regex

```
/(?:^|\s)([A-Z]+)(?:\s|$)/g
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC7wT6)